# Google Calendar API: 403 Calendar Usage Limits Exceeded Using Service Account

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

The entire Google facing side of the application is written in .NET.

I am trying to use a service account created by an admin account to create events on a resource. I am able to create events and specify any parameter except for attendees.

A couple notes:

- We have a g suite license and are well within our quota.
- The service account has write access to the calendar.
- I have tried only adding attendees within my own domain and this does not fix the problem.
- I have tried not sending email notifications and get the same response.
- All events are being added to the same calendar.
- Requests with no attendees work completely fine.
- I've seen this page: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en and assumed that I just needed to let my requests refresh. However, after waiting out the weekend I came back and still got the error message.
- When the message persisted I created a new project in the google developer console with a new service account. This project was also made using a different email (this email belonged to an admin) under the same domain. The first request on the project resulted in the same error.

  - The original project made ~500 requests over the course of 3 days during testing. Most of these requests were made in a javascript application. I was able to add attendees in these events. I eventually switched the requests to the backend with a service account and have yet to be able to add attendees since then.

This is the code I am using to generate the Event. Get Attendees just returns a list of EventAttendees for each email in a list.

```
var attendees = GetAttendees(request.Emails);

var googleEvent = new Event()
{
    Summary = request.Title,
    Location = request.Location,
    Description = request.Description,
    Start = new EventDateTime()
    {
        DateTime = request.MeetingDate,
        TimeZone = "America/Chicago"
    },
    End = new EventDateTime()
    {
        DateTime = request.EndTime,
        TimeZone = "America/Chicago"
    },
    Attendees = attendees
};
```

Executing any request with attendees results in the following response:

```
{
  "error": "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nCalendar usage limits exceeded. [403]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Calendar usage limits exceeded.] Location[ - ] Reason[quotaExceeded] Domain[usageLimits]\r\n]\r\n",
  "exception": {
    "ServiceName": "calendar",
    "Error": {
      "Errors": [
        {
          "Domain": "usageLimits",
          "Reason": "quotaExceeded",
          "Message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded.",
          "LocationType": null,
          "Location": null
        }
      ],
      "Code": 403,
      "Message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
    },
    "HttpStatusCode": 403,
    "Message": "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nCalendar usage limits exceeded. [403]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Calendar usage limits exceeded.] Location[ - ] Reason[quotaExceeded] Domain[usageLimits]\r\n]\r\n",
    "Data": {},
    "InnerException": null,
    "StackTrace": " ..."
  },
  "type": "Google.GoogleApiException"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### This could be a bug

Currently, many people are experiencing a similar issue and there is already a [filed bug report for this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/141704931) on Public Issue tracker.

There are many [possible reasons](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en) for `Calendar usage limits exceeded`, but if you are sure that you are not exceeding any of them, it is possible that the existing bug is the reason for your issue. In this case, I suggest you to give a "star" to the bug report to increase its visibility and hope that it will be fixed soon.